# AVCaptureMovieFileOutputで撮影した動画を正方形にリサイズしたい

Tags: swift, swift2

AVCaptureMovieFileOutputを使って撮影した動画を正方形にリサイズしたいです。

撮影時にはpreviewとして正方形にしたUIViewに以下のプロパティを指定したAVCaptureVideoPreviewLayerを設定しています。

```
videoGravity = AVLayerVideoGravityResizeAspectFill
```

previewでは正方形ですが、当然実ファイル（動画)はiPhoneのカメラサイズ（長方形)なので、
それをpreviewと同じように正方形でリサイズしたいと思っています。

何かいい方法をご存知の方、ご教授いただければ幸いです。

Answer (score 1):

英語の記事ですが、このような内容のものが見つかりました。

[Record square video in iOS](http://www.netwalk.be/article/record-square-video-ios)

撮影されてファイルの形で保存されたビデオを編集して正方形のビデオを出力するという内容ですので、ほぼご質問の趣旨に沿っているのではないかと思います。

今は実際にビデオ撮影を行うサンプルアプリを作る暇がありませんので、記事中のObjective-CコードをSwift2に変換したものだけ掲載しておきます。ご自分のアプリに組み込めそうでしたら一度お試しいただければと思います。

```
    // output file
    guard let docURL = NSFileManager.defaultManager().URLsForDirectory(.DocumentDirectory, inDomains: .UserDomainMask).last else {
        print("Failed to find Document directory")
        return
    }
    let outputURL = docURL.URLByAppendingPathComponent("output2.mov")
    if NSFileManager.defaultManager().fileExistsAtPath(outputURL.path!) {
        _ = try? NSFileManager.defaultManager().removeItemAtURL(outputURL)
    }

    // input file
    let asset = AVAsset(URL: fileURL)

    let composition = AVMutableComposition()
    composition.addMutableTrackWithMediaType(AVMediaTypeVideo, preferredTrackID: kCMPersistentTrackID_Invalid)

    // input clip
    let clipVideoTrack = asset.tracksWithMediaType(AVMediaTypeVideo)[0]

    // make it square
    let videoComposition = AVMutableVideoComposition()
    videoComposition.renderSize = CGSize(width: clipVideoTrack.naturalSize.height, height: clipVideoTrack.naturalSize.height)
    videoComposition.frameDuration = CMTimeMake(1, 30)

    let instruction = AVMutableVideoCompositionInstruction()
    instruction.timeRange = CMTimeRangeMake(kCMTimeZero, CMTimeMakeWithSeconds(60, 30))

    // rotate to portrait
    let transformer = AVMutableVideoCompositionLayerInstruction(assetTrack: clipVideoTrack)
    let t1 = CGAffineTransformMakeTranslation(clipVideoTrack.naturalSize.height, -(clipVideoTrack.naturalSize.width - clipVideoTrack.naturalSize.height) / 2)
    let t2 = CGAffineTransformRotate(t1, CGFloat(M_PI_2))

    let finalTransform = t2
    transformer.setTransform(finalTransform, atTime: kCMTimeZero)
    instruction.layerInstructions = [transformer]
    videoComposition.instructions = [instruction]

    // export
    guard let exporter = AVAssetExportSession(asset: asset, presetName: AVAssetExportPresetHighestQuality) else {
        print("Failed to create AVAssetExportSession")
        return
    }
    exporter.videoComposition = videoComposition
    exporter.outputURL = outputURL
    exporter.outputFileType = AVFileTypeQuickTimeMovie

    exporter.exportAsynchronouslyWithCompletionHandler {
        NSLog("Exporting done!")
    }
```

(撮影済みビデオが`fileURL`に(元記事なら`filePath`に)存在するという前提でこのコードを走らせるとDocumentディレクトリ内に"output2.mov"と言う名前の変換済みファイルができる、と言うことのようです。)

変換ミスなど、何かお気付きの点があればコメント等でお知らせください。

Comment: ありがとうございます。上記のコードを参考に無事実装できました。ご丁寧にありがとうございました

Comment: @yoshinbo さん、ご報告ありがとうございます。そのうち時間が取れたら自分でも試してみようと思っているのですが、無事実装できたという方がおられるなら心強いです。あなたのご経験が私を含め他の開発者の役に立つこともあるかと思いますので、お時間が取れる時には是非そのつもりでこのサイトを覗いてみてください。それでは良いアプリを。